# Is there a way to remove points from a contour outside a given circle in Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Let's say I have a contour which is meant to represent the shape of the hand. The issue is, the contour also contains other parts of the arm (i.e. wrist, forearm, upper arm, etc.) To find the position of the hand's center, I'm looking at the combinations (size 3) of the defect points of the convex hull, finding the center of circle which is tangent to these 3 points, and averaging the most reasonable ones together to gain a rough understanding of where the hand's center is.

With this averaged center, I'd like to be able to remove points on my given contour which don't fall inside some radius that's likely to determine the width of the hand - in other words, cutoff points that don't fall inside this circle. I could simply iterate through each contour point and remove these points, but that would be horribly inefficient because of Python loops' speed. Is there a faster or more efficient way of doing this, perhaps using some inbuilt OpenCV functions or otherwise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting follow-up to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212270/how-to-speedup-checking-every-possible-combination-python-numpy).

You can remove the unwanted points by boolean indexing:

```
import numpy as np
hand_contour = np.random.rand(60,2)  # you can use np.squeeze on the data from opencv to get rid of that annoying singleton axis (60,1,2)->(60,2)
# You have found the center of the palm and a possible radius
center = np.array([.3, .1])
radius = .3
mask = (hand_contour[:,0] - center[0])**2 + (hand_contour[:,1] - center[1])**2 < radius**2
within_palm = hand_contour[mask,:]  # Only selects those values within that circle.
```

You could also mask the unwanted values, with a `masked_array`, but if you're not interested in keeping the original data, the above method is the way to go.