# Speeding up selecting sets of 3 nodes that form triangles with given min and max side length

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, numpy

I've got a list of about 60 points, from which I'm generating all possible combinations of size 3. I'm trying to determine whether any of the 3 points are within certain distance parameters - that is, not too close to each other, and not too far from each other (say, no point can be less than 10 units to the next nearest point, and no point can be more than 100 units from the furthest point).

I've got code to do so here:

```
def setPalmCombinations(self):
    # Testing confirms that the range of distances is about 5 - 10 for
    # minimum distance between points, and anywhere from 150 - 200 for max
    # distance between points. 10 and 100 should be reasonable cutoffs.
    minDistance = 10
    maxDistance = 100
    startTime = time.time()
    iter = itertools.combinations(self.handContour, 3)
    def distanceCheck(points):
        A = points[0][0]
        B = points[1][0]
        C = points[2][0]
        AB = np.linalg.norm(A - B)
        if not(minDistance < AB < maxDistance): return None
        BC = np.linalg.norm(B - C)
        if not(minDistance < BC < maxDistance): return None
        CA = np.linalg.norm(C - A)
        if not(minDistance < CA < maxDistance): return None
        return np.array([A, B, C])
    a = [distanceCheck(i) for i in iter]
    print time.time() - startTime
```

However, just generating this list of possible combinations takes roughly .4 to .5 seconds, which is far too slow. Is there a way I can optimize this calculation (or fundamentally redo the algorithm so that it's not simply a brute force search) so that I can get the time down to about a realtime calculation (that is, 30ish times a second).

I was thinking about possibly generating a list of the distances between every point, sorting it, and looking for the points with distances toward the center of the cutoff range, but I think that may actually be slower than what I'm doing now.

I'm also trying to figure out some more intelligent algorithm given the fact that the points are originally stored in order of how they define the contour - I should be able to eliminate some points before and after each point in the list when making the combinations ... however, when I tried to generate the combinations using this fact with Python's default for loops, it ended up being slower than simply using itertools and generating everything.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your Question is very broadly formed are you searching in a graph? Or a Point-Cloud?

Comment: The points are currently stored as a list of numpy arrays to represent the coordinates. The ordering of the list is such that each point can be connected to the next with a line and have the end result trace a contour of the object, which is a hand in this case. I could try to construct other data structures from this data but that may be too slow.

Comment: For me it sounds like a Graph, and Graph should be stored in tree like structures, so that you can do things like Nearest Neighbor Search. scipy numpy has a KD-Tree for example which is handy.

Comment: Could you expand on what you actually want to accomplish? As I understand it now, you have a list of points that form a contour (of a hand) if they are connected in order. Now you search for 3-element subsets that are within a certain distance range from one an other. Why? What is the goal? As the number of possible 3-element subsets is N over 3 which is growing factorial, your only hope for speeding up things significantly is to avoid having to build that combinations list, IMHO.

Comment: You seem to be taking only the distances between the first coordinate components into account: `B = points[1][0]`, in other words, the "x-component". What is `self.handContour.shape`? I'm assuming it is `(60,2)`, but your code seems to indicate otherwise. Are you only interested in checking whether the x-distance is within bounds?

Comment: As Oliver W pointed out you appear to be comparing only the x-coordinates, in which case using norm() is overkill abs() would be just as effective. Also your result list would contain triplets of x-coordinates, not sure of how much use that would be.

Comment: @user1767754, the points are originally stored simply in a list when received from a function in OpenCV. I can convert it to another format, but I'm not sure that it would be worth the time. However, if some graph traversal algorithm can speed this process up significantly, I'd love to know.

Comment: OliverW., openCV returns the contour a bit weirdly and in fact the shape of `self.handContour.shape = (~60, 1, 2)`. The second `[0]` is to expose the two coordinates for points - I'd like to compare both coordinates and not just the X. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Peter, the goal of doing this is to figure which 3 points I can draw a circle through (that is, circle that goes through all 3 points) such that the circle is inside the convex hull of the contour. There will be many, many possible circle candidates from these points, so I'd then look for the largest circle. In the end, the goal is to figure out the largest circle that can fit inside the contour in order to roughly figure out where the palm's center is. I've tried to use the defect points of the convex hull, but that isn't accurate when the hand is closed.

Comment: @Holyhades666 do you want the circle actually to go through those 3 points or merely be inscribed by the convex hull? Those are 2 entirely different things. If it's the latter, your current way of solving it, seems like a good idea, although there might be other ways (centroiding eg if the fingers aren't taken into account). If it's the former, this approach isn't correct, as you need perpendicular bisectors for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first calculate the pairwise distance between all points, filter out those that meet your specifications (the `dist_min` and `dist_max`) and then check if a combination of three such nodes still matches the criteria (because I'm only checking pairwise - once, for speed).

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

points = np.random.rand(100,2)  # could be nodes in 3 dimensions too, but you specify a handpalm, so I'm guessing your contour is merely 2D

def palm_combinations(points, dist_min=.0, dist_max=.05):
    dists = pdist(points)
    # This matrix lists the distance between each pair of nodes 
    # (represented by their column and row index, so that the mat[i,j] 
    # represents the distance between points[i,:], points[j,:])
    mat = squareform(dists)  

    mask = (mat > dist_min) & (mat < dist_max)

    two_good_legs = {}  # store all combinations of point indices where "two legs" of the triangles have a distance that matches the spec.
    myinds = []
    for rowind, row in enumerate(mask):
        relevant = row[rowind+1:]  # distance to a point itself is always zero, hence exclude from list
        inds = np.where(relevant)[0] + (rowind+1)
        myinds.append(inds)
        two_good_legs[rowind] = list(itertools.combinations(inds, 2))

    triangles = []
    # The only thing left to do now is to check if the third leg's norm is also within spec.
    for k,v in two_good_legs.items():
        for tup in v:
            if tup[1] in myinds[tup[0]]:
                triangles.append((k, tup[0], tup[1]))
    return triangles
```

`triangles` will list all the indices within the points that meet your specifications. If you want to get back to actual coordinates, just get `points[triangles,:]`.
You could visualize all this with:

```
import maptlotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.triplot(points[:,0], points[:,1], triangles)
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'ko ')
```

Timing differences between your implementation (modified to exclude the unknown `[0]` indexing, see my comment) show this:

```
In [12]: %timeit  my_implementation(points, .1, .15)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.58 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit your_implementation(points, .1, .15)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.32 s per loop
```

With points being of the shape `(100,2)`, so about a 1470x speed increase on my machine.

You could increase the speed slightly, if you get rid of the call to `squareform`, which is the bottleneck according to the profiler, and it isn't strictly necessary but it makes the code more readable ("Readability counts." cfr. the Zen of Python, by Tim Peters). For that you would make the following changes:

```
def palm_combinations(points, dist_min=.0, dist_max=.05):
    dists = pdist(points)
    mask = (dists > dist_min) & (dists < dist_max)
    two_good_legs, myinds, triangles = {}, [], []
    s = points.shape[0]
    ind_u1, ind_un = 0, s - 1
    for rowind in xrange(s-1):
        relevant = mask[ind_u1:ind_un]
        ind_u1 = ind_un
        ind_un += s - 1*(rowind+2)
        inds = np.where(relevant)[0] + (rowind+1)
        myinds.append(inds)
        two_good_legs[rowind] = list(itertools.combinations(inds, 2))
    for k,v in two_good_legs.items():
        for tup in v:
            if tup[1] in myinds[tup[0]]:
                triangles.append((k, tup[0], tup[1]))
    return triangles
```

However, the speed gains won't be noticeable for small datasets.

Comment: This seems to accomplish what I need perfectly. Thank you. Could you perhaps take a look at the comment I posted above to see if there's a way to further improve this algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

You can speedup using numpy. Assuming `comb` is your already calculated possible combinations, you can easily vectorize distance calculations:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> comb = np.array(list(comb))
>>> dists = comb - np.roll(comb, -1)
# L2 norm
>>> dists = dists**2
```

dists will be a `Nx3` array containing `AB` `BC` and `CA` distances respectively.

Mask it with your conditions:

```
>>> mask = (dists > minDist) & (dists < maxDist)
```

Find rows where all distances satisfy the conditon:

```
>>> rows = np.all(mask, axis=1)
```

return combinations that satisfy conditions:

```
>>> comb[rows]
```

UPDATE: Just noticed that this is still quite slow for large N. Here it is the function that contains all the above steps:

```
>>> def palm_combinations(points, min_dist=10, max_dist=100): 
        combs = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(points, 3)))
        dists = (combs - np.roll(combs, -1))**2
        mask = (dists > min_dist) & (dists < max_dist)
        return combs[np.all(mask, axis=1)]
```

For a sample data of 100 points:

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(100) * 500
>>> %timeit palm_combinations(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 79.5 ms per loop
```

The bottleneck of the function is the generation of all the combinations:

```
>>> %timeit combs = np.array(list(itertools.combinations(a, 3)))
10 loops, best of 3: 69.2 ms per loop
```

UPDATE 2: It can be speeded-up with a bit more complicated approach. Using `np.fromiter`:

```
# Define combinations data type (3 float each combination)
>>> dt = np.dtype('f,f,f')
# Fast numpy array conversion
>>> combs = np.fromiter(itertools.combinations(points, 3), dt)
```

The function would be something like:

```
>>> def palm_combinations(points, min_dist=10, max_dist=100): 
        dt = np.dtype('f,f,f')
        combs = np.fromiter(itertools.combinations(points, 3), dt)
        combs = combs.view('f').reshape(-1,3)
        dists = (combs - np.roll(combs, -1))**2
        mask = (dists > min_dist) & (dists < max_dist)
        return combs[np.all(mask, axis=1)]
```

And the speed test:

```
>>> %timeit palm_combinations(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.8 ms per loop
```

For N=100

Answer (score 1):

If the number of contour points is very large you might want to try an heuristic approach.
That is take three random points, (check min and max distances,) calculate the radius of the corresponding circle, compare to previous calculated radius, repeat. You would have to figure in some kind of stopping criteria, like max number of iterations, or no better radius found over the last x iterations, or radii growth rate below x percent, or some combination of those.

Apart from that, in regards to your clarification comment under your question:
Either your terminology or your approach is off.
There is no guaranty that a circle going through thee of the contour points is inside the convex hull of the contour points. Imagine for example a spread hand, the shape will have concave segments, if all three points are within one such segment the circle will lie outside the hand.
What I think you mean is the circle inscribed within the convex hull of each three point set.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - the goal here is to generate all possible combinations of 3 points which meet basic distance criteria, figure out circles for all of them, and then see which of those circles lie inside the convex hull by checking to see if the 4 points above, below, right, and left of the center are inside the hull. The issue is, I've got a lot of potential circles and this process is quite slow.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. But if I understood you correctly you will then have a collection of circles which are inside the convex hull and the final step is to choose the largest one. If thats the case (and if the number of points is large (with N=100 you have 160.000 triplets to check; with N=1000 there are 160 Million to check) then you could still benefit from an heuristic approach, as it should be sufficient to find a pretty large circle, not necessarily the largest one there is.